# Rails 5: Does ActiveRecord uses id sequence when using build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 models which have 1 to 1 relationship, namely `Project` and `Inspection`, the structure is something like,

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_one  :inspection

  def inspection_required?
    (inspection || build_inspection).required?
  end
end

class Inspection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project

  def required?
    required_saved || API.check({ id: id})
  end
end
```

As you see above, for a `Project` if we don't have an `Inspection` it does `build_inspection`. I looked at the database and it seems like the `inspection` record `id` skips the sequence as shown below,

```
ID | PROJECT_ID   | VENDOR_TYPE | REQUIRED_SAVED | CREATED_AT          | UPDATED_AT           |
---|--------------|-------------|----------------|---------------------|----------------------|
1  | 7983f1a33d55 | vendor1     | false          | 2020-09-12 00:43:52 | 2020-09-12 00:43:52  |
3  | asdereww224f | vendor2     | true           | 2020-09-12 00:48:51 | 2020-09-12 00:48:51  |
4  | 3q3332reere1 | vendor1     | false          | 2020-09-13 01:02:53 | 2020-09-13 01:02:53  |
7  | 1df343qe233a | vendor2     | true           | 2020-09-14 02:43:51 | 2020-09-14 02:43:51  |
```

The ID column is skipping sequence.
So my question is, *does `build_inpsection` is using the Sequence generated by Postgres SQL even when we don't save the record?*

Rails version: `Rails 5.2.3`
Postgres version: `9.6`

Comment: No. `build_association` does not save the record. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one

Comment: That my understanding too nad confirmed that the record is not saved. 
But I am not able to find a reasonable explanation of why the `id`'s are been skipped since there is no delete or destroy anywhere in the code been called.